# Can I combine these two snippets of Javascript code to filter and format text on input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form input field where people can write in text. I want to use Javascript and jQuery to force their input into a particular format as they type. Text should be first-letter-capitalized, and strictly only alphabetical characters and spaces allowed.

So, the resulting format will be "Firstword Secondword", or, "Firstword Secondword Thirdword", and so on.

"Firstword SECONDWORD", "FirSTwOrD SecONdWoRD", "123 Secondword", or anything else will be rejected.

I have this code which forces only alphabetical characters (though some numbers seem to be sneaking through somehow... I think because there's some delay in keypresses or something? I can't write more than one number in a row, but it's still allowing some numbers).

```
$('#input').keypress(function(event){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if (! txt.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/)){
        $(this).val(txt.replace(char, ''));
    }
});
```

I have this code which should, in theory, force the first letter of every word to be capitalized:

```
return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
```

Ideally, I'd like to combine them into one function, but I'm not sure if that's possible. One acts on each character as one types, the other acts on the string as a whole.

Can I combine these two snippets of code to get the effect I want?

*And can I ensure the first one doesn't allow any numbers through?*

Comment: You could, but there are several names that don't necessarily follow this format. What about Irish "'O'..." surnames, or the South African "DuPlessis", or "Neil deGrasse Tyson"?

Comment: Do you want to completely prevent the user from inputting numbers (when a number key is pressed, it doesn't show at all in the input) or do you want to prevent from submit? If the latter is the case, you should consider the [pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @vlaz Awesome article haha

Comment: @JakubJankowski, I want to be able to prevent the numbers as the user presses keys, before the submit button is pressed.

Comment: Save you a lot of work doing *what*? If people enter their names in weird cases, shrug and use that.

Comment: @TRiG, thank you for responding. However, I thought Stack Exchange was about solving technical issues, not questioning motives. Do I really need to justify why I want to do a task in order to get an answer on how to do it? My personal situation is what it is, it's too complicated and off topic to explain here, and I'm just looking for a way to combine two pieces of code, that's all.